# Remove special characters in jinja template in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use dag's run_id in jinja template for having a unique name for a file across all tasks.

```
filename=f"""{{{{var.value.FILE_PATH}}}}{{{{dag.dag_id}}}}__{{{{run_id | regex_replace ("[^A-Za-z0-9]","")}}}}"""
```

But it fails with the following error:

> ERROR - Failed to execute task: no filter named 'regex_replace'.

How can I remove special characters from the run_id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own filters in airflow, you can provide them to your dag by adding the argument:

```py
DAG(
    ...,
    user_defined_filters={
        "<filter_name>": <filter_method>, # "regex_replace": regex_replace
    }
)
```

If you have some problems with this approach, you can create a upstream python task to process whatever you want, then you can access its result with xcom.